# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

I downloaded the library from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils
and followed the steps `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup`
but I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity
```

I've added the library project to the MainActivity, as it described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup)

What is wrong with Google documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this
Go to `Properties` -> `Java Build Path` -> `Order and Export`

You should see the selected `src` and `gen`, and the order must be first `src` and then `gen`.

**`Android Private Libraries`** must be checked!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue. Removing Android Dependencies under Java Build Path/Libraryies solved it for me.